# Swift unable to load chat messages not loading newest at the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on this messaging app and I'm able to fetch the first group of messages, newest message at the bottom using: `.order(by: TIMESTAMP, descending: false).limit(toLast: 5)` , but, when I try to load the second group, the tableView is not populated.
If I use `.order(by: TIMESTAMP, descending: true).limit(to: 5)` for the first call, it loads the messages but newest message at the top and if i scroll, it loads the older messages with no issues. Not sure how to make it work the other way around. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code. Thank you.

**Code**

```swift
    func fetchChatMessages() {
            fetchMoreDocs = true
            var query: Query!
            
            if messages.isEmpty {
                query = MESSAGES_COLLECTION.document(currentUID!).collection(user.memberId).order(by: TIMESTAMP, descending: false).limit(toLast: 5)
            } else {
                query = MESSAGES_COLLECTION.document(currentUID!).collection(user.memberId).order(by: TIMESTAMP, descending: false).start(afterDocument: self.lastDocument!).limit(to: 5)
            }
            query.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error..\(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else if snapshot!.isEmpty {
                    self.fetchMoreDocs = false
                    return
                } else {
                    let newMessages = Message.parseData(snapshot: snapshot)
                    self.messages.append(contentsOf: newMessages)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.chatRoomTV.reloadData()
                        self.scrollToBottom()
                        self.fetchMoreDocs = false
                    }
                }
                self.lastDocument = snapshot!.documents.last
            }
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
            let position = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            let maxOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height
            if maxOffset - position <= 50 {
                print("Fetch older messages")
                fetchChatMessages()
            }}
```

Comment: I believe addSnapshotListener should only be called once. I can’t remember the other method call but snapshot listeners isn’t ideal for this situation.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez I use the snapshotListener for all new incoming messages. My issue is sorting the messages, newest at the bottom.

Comment: If descending true works, you can reverse your array? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/reverse()

I am not sure if your lastDocument is where it should be but I am not sure of your logic.